# The list item is disappearing while using primeng drag/drop

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using the Primeng picklist, when I'm trying to drag an item from list to another, the item disappear until the item dropped.

```html
<p-dialog [(visible)]="showMarker"  (onHide)="hideDialogChild()" [contentStyle]="{'overflow':'visible'}" header="'Marker List'" [modal]="true">
    <p-pickList [source]="sourceMarkers" [target]="targetMarkers" sourceHeader="Available markers" targetHeader="Associated Markers" dragdrop="true"
        [responsive]="true" [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" filterBy="markername"
        sourceFilterPlaceholder="Search by name" targetFilterPlaceholder="Search by name">
        <ng-template let-marker pTemplate="item">
            <div class="product-list-detail">
                <h5 class="mb-2">{{markername}}</h5>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-pickList>

  
</p-dialog>
```

this link is a snapshot video to show the current behavior [pick list issue](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnVD3W4EtUB3gah-J7Vx2EyiBL6ybQ?e=P994qz)

Here is a running code on stackblitze:
[Code snippet for picker issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-picklist-demo-dsadet?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Please share the ts code, if possible a working example with the issue replicated on stackblitz!

Comment: Sure, I will add it

Comment: Here is the running code 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-picklist-demo-dsadet?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the stackblitz, its a `z-index` css issue, please add the below style to `style.css`.

```
.p-picklist-item:not(.cdk-drag-disabled) {
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 1130 !important;
}
```

[`forked stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-picklist-demo-vml1v5)

Comment: If you are using the PickList inside a dialog, you also have to change the z-index of this one.